# Error: more than one library with package name 'com.facebook.android

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

Friends,
I am using Facebook SDK in my project, using Unity2017.1.1, while building this error occurs.
Please help

CommandInvokationFailure: Gradle build failed.
C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_261\bin\java.exe -classpath "C:\Program Files\Unity 2017.1.1\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\Tools\gradle\lib\gradle-launcher-2.14.jar" org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain "assembleRelease"

stderr[

**FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.**

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':processReleaseResources'.

> **Error: more than one library with package name 'com.facebook.android'**

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
  ]
  stdout[
  Incremental java compilation is an incubating feature.
  :preBuild UP-TO-DATE
  :preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
  :checkReleaseManifest
  :preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
  :unity-android-resources:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
  :unity-android-resources:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
  :unity-android-resources:compileReleaseNdk UP-TO-DATE
  :unity-android-resources:compileLint
  :unity-android-resources:copyReleaseLint UP-TO-DATE
  :unity-android-resources:mergeReleaseProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
  :unity-android-resources:packageReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
  :unity-android-resources:checkReleaseManifest
  :unity-android-resources:prepareReleaseDependencies
  :unity-android-resources:compileReleaseRenderscript
  :unity-android-resources:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
  :unity-android-resources:generateReleaseResources
  :unity-android-resources:packageReleaseResources
  :unity-android-resources:compileReleaseAidl
  :unity-android-resources:generateReleaseBuildConfig
  :unity-android-resources:mergeReleaseShaders
  :unity-android-resources:compileReleaseShaders
  :unity-android-resources:generateReleaseAssets
  :unity-android-resources:mergeReleaseAssets
  :unity-android-resources:processReleaseManifest
  :unity-android-resources:processReleaseResources
  :unity-android-resources:generateReleaseSources
  :unity-android-resources:incrementalReleaseJavaCompilationSafeguard
  :unity-android-resources:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
  :unity-android-resources:processReleaseJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
  :unity-android-resources:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForRelease
  :unity-android-resources:transformClassesAndResourcesWithSyncLibJarsForRelease
  :unity-android-resources:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders
  :unity-android-resources:transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForRelease
  :unity-android-resources:transformNative_libsWithSyncJniLibsForRelease
  :unity-android-resources:bundleRelease
  :prepareAndroidxAppcompatAppcompat100Library UP-TO-DATE
  :prepareAndroidxArchCoreCoreRuntime200Library UP-TO-DATE
  :prepareAndroidxAsynclayoutinflaterAsynclayoutinflater100Library UP-TO-DATE
  :prepareAndroidxBrowserBrowser100Library UP-TO-DATE
  :prepareAndroidxCardviewCardview100Library UP-TO-DATE
  :prepareAndroidxCoordinatorlayoutCoordinatorlayout100Library UP-TO-DATE
  :prepareAndroidxCoreCore100Library UP-TO-DATE
  :prepareAndroidxCursoradapterCursoradapter100Library UP-TO-DATE
  :prepareAndroidxCustomviewCustomview100Library UP-TO-DATE
  :prepareAndroidxDocumentfileDocumentfile100Library UP-TO-DATE
  :prepareAndroidxDrawerlayoutDrawerlayout100Library UP-TO-DATE
  :prepareAndroidxFragmentFragment100Library UP-TO-DATE
  :prepareAndroidxInterpolatorInterpolator100Library UP-TO-DATE
  :prepareAndroidxLegacyLegacySupportCoreUi100Library UP-TO-DATE
  :prepareAndroidxLegacyLegacySupportCoreUtils100Library UP-TO-DATE
  :prepareAndroidxLegacyLegacySupportV4100Library UP-TO-DATE
  :prepareAndroidxLifecycleLifecycleLivedata200Library UP-TO-DATE
  :prepareAndroidxLifecycleLifecycleLivedataCore200Library UP-TO-DATE
  :prepareAndroidxLifecycleLifecycleRuntime200Library UP-TO-DATE
  :prepareAndroidxLifecycleLifecycleViewmodel200Library UP-TO-DATE
  :prepareAndroidxLoaderLoader100Library UP-TO-DATE
  :prepareAndroidxLocalbroadcastmanagerLocalbroadcastmanager100Library UP-TO-DATE
  :prepareAndroidxMediaMedia100Library UP-TO-DATE
  :prepareAndroidxPrintPrint100Library UP-TO-DATE
  :prepareAndroidxSlidingpanelayoutSlidingpanelayout100Library UP-TO-DATE
  :prepareAndroidxSwiperefreshlayoutSwiperefreshlayout100Library UP-TO-DATE
  :prepareAndroidxVectordrawableVectordrawable100Library UP-TO-DATE
  :prepareAndroidxVectordrawableVectordrawableAnimated100Library UP-TO-DATE
  :prepareAndroidxVersionedparcelableVersionedparcelable100Library UP-TO-DATE
  :prepareAndroidxViewpagerViewpager100Library UP-TO-DATE
  :prepareAnimatedVectorDrawable2340Library UP-TO-DATE
  :prepareCardviewV72340Library UP-TO-DATE
  :prepareComAndroidSupportAnimatedVectorDrawable2600Alpha1Library UP-TO-DATE
  :prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72600Alpha1Library UP-TO-DATE
  :prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCompat2600Alpha1Library UP-TO-DATE
  :prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCoreUi2600Alpha1Library UP-TO-DATE
  :prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCoreUtils2600Alpha1Library UP-TO-DATE
  :prepareComAndroidSupportSupportFragment2600Alpha1Library UP-TO-DATE
  :prepareComAndroidSupportSupportMediaCompat2600Alpha1Library UP-TO-DATE
  :prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42600Alpha1Library UP-TO-DATE
  :prepareComAndroidSupportSupportVectorDrawable2600Alpha1Library UP-TO-DATE
  :prepareCommonLibrary UP-TO-DATE
  :prepareCustomtabs2340Library UP-TO-DATE
  :prepareFacebookAndroidSdk4170Library UP-TO-DATE
  :prepareFacebookAndroidSdk460Library UP-TO-DATE
  :prepareFacebookAndroidWrapper790Library UP-TO-DATE
  :prepareFacebookAndroidWrapperReleaseLibrary UP-TO-DATE
  :prepareGoogleAIDLLibrary UP-TO-DATE
  :prepareGooglePlayLibrary UP-TO-DATE
  :prepareGradleOutUnityAndroidResourcesUnspecifiedLibrary
  :preparePlayServicesBasement1102Library UP-TO-DATE
  :prepareSupportCompat2520Library UP-TO-DATE
  :prepareSupportCoreUi2520Library UP-TO-DATE
  :prepareSupportCoreUtils2520Library UP-TO-DATE
  :prepareSupportFragment2520Library UP-TO-DATE
  :prepareSupportMediaCompat2520Library UP-TO-DATE
  :prepareSupportV42340Library UP-TO-DATE
  :prepareSupportV42520Library UP-TO-DATE
  :prepareSupportVectorDrawable2340Library UP-TO-DATE
  :prepareReleaseDependencies
  :compileReleaseAidl UP-TO-DATE
  :compileReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
  :generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
  :mergeReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE
  :compileReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE
  :generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
  :mergeReleaseAssets
  :generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
  :generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
  :mergeReleaseResources
  :processReleaseManifest
  :processReleaseResources FAILED

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 37.752 secs
]
exit code: 1
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.RunJava (System.String args, System.String workingdir, UnityEditor.Android.Progress progress)
Rethrow as GradleInvokationException: Gradle build failed
UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.RunJava (System.String args, System.String workingdir, UnityEditor.Android.Progress progress)
UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (System.String workingdir, System.String task, UnityEditor.Android.Progress progress)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.BuildGradleProject.Execute (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context)
UnityEditor.HostView:OnGUI()

Comment: If you look at your service or web references do you have duplicate facebook references there?

Comment: I updated the Facebook SDK, may be duplicate occurs. But i solved using below method i mentioned

Answer (score 0):

Solved this error by deleting all facebook related file from **Lib** folder.
Don't know this is the solution or not,but that error gone.